# How can I close the print window only after user has printed/closed the window || How can I preview an image with the QPrintPreviewDialog

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

**Overview:**
I need a way to have a printer dialog to print an image (a modern looking one is preferred)

**Description:**
I tried to find a way to print an image with a printer dialog and I found `win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", "test.jpg", 'None', None, 0)`
But to make that work I need a wait after that and when the wait is over the window will close.. and I want it to close ONLY when the user has pressed print or closed the window...
Is there a way of doing that?
and it would be even better if you could link me to another module/way to have that printer dialog maybe a more modern one.. (not the PyQt5 one) because the win32api one looks kinda old school

**Edit:** So I found this piece of code -

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QTextEdit
import sys
from PySide2.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintPreviewDialog



myapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
previewDialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(printer, window)
previewDialog.exec_()
myapp.exec_()
sys.exit()
```

Source (I have minimized the code above as much as possible): https://codeloop.org/pyside2-print-preview-dialog/

But I don't know how to preview an image (this is using PySide2) please help

Comment: I'm not convinced that `ShellExecute` would ever display any sort of PyQt5 dialog.

Comment: what do you mean? I didn't say it would..

Answer (score 0):

Acroding to the document of [**ShellExecuteA function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea), nCmdShow parameter is passed via calls to ShellExecute, so I tried every nCmdShow parameters in this function, but it didn't work like you want. It always close the print window after user has printed/closed the window.I suggest you use [**Print Spooler API Functions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printing-and-print-spooler-functions) to write your own printing interface, so that you can wait for the user's further operation after printing.

Comment: How do i use it with python? Can i get an example?

Comment: And I actually want it to close after the user has printed/closed the window..

Comment: Using Python to call WinAPI to implement what you want is a bit more complicated, so I suggest you use Python directly,

Comment: That's what I'm asking.. what can i use in python

Comment: You can make interfaces in DLL or SO and use Python to call them.